# Android: Why did my background color mysteriously change

Tags: android, colors, background, android-4.4-kitkat

I had an app crash today and afterward the background color and the text color are different.  The only change today has been adding a button and that wasn't checked in.  I've seen this happen on another device that doesn't have the new code.  There's nothing in the code that should affect the color.

I tried reinstalling the app, clearing the cache, restarting the device, and nothing helped.  Any ideas?

I'm using a 1st-gen Nexus 7 with Kit Kat?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build of your app?

Comment: Yes, I did do a clean build